# Show that Set is a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $f_i\colon \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ i=1,2,3$ be defined by

$f_1(x)=x_1x_3-x_2^2 \\
f_2(x)=x_2x_4 -x_3^2\\
f_3(x)=x_1x_4-x_2x_3$

I want to show that $M=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^4 -\{0\} \colon f_1(x)=f_2(x)=f_3(x)=0\}$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

My problem is, that I can only show that it is a 1 dimensional submanfold.

It is clear, that every $f_i\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^4)$ and that the functional matrix

$\frac{\partial (f_1,f_2,f_3)}{\partial( x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_3 & -2x_2 & x_1 & 0 \\
0 & x_4 & -2x_3 & x_2 \\
x_4 & -x_3 & -x_2 & x_1
\end{pmatrix}$

has rank 3, therefore it is surjective. This should show that $M$ is a  1 dimensional submanifold.
At this point I have no idea, since if I remember correctly, the dimension of a submanifold is unique (think it follows from the uniqueness of the atlas for $M$).

Comment: It has rank $3$ generically, but what happens when the polynomials vanish?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by generically? The point $x=0$ is excluded by requirement. The polynomial can vanish, but why would that be a problem for the rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of points that satisfy the equations $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=f_3(x)=0$ can be described as the image of the map
$$
\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4,
$$
where
$$
(s,t)\mapsto(s^3,s^2t,st^2,t^3).
$$
Plugging these points into the Jacobian matrix that you wrote above gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
st^2&-2s^2t&s^3&0\\
0&t^3&-2st^2&s^2t\\
t^3&-st^2&-s^2t&s^3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, observe that $t$ times row $1$ minus $s$ times row $3$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}st^3&-2s^2t^2&s^3t&0\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}st^3&-s^2t^2&-s^3t&s^4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-s^2t^2&2s^3t&-s^4\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is $-\frac{s^2}{t}$ times row $2$.  So, the rank of this image is $2$.  At all (most?) other points, the rank is $3$ (this is what is meant by generically).

Comment: I understand, my mistake was simply missing that for some points e.g. $(1,0,0,1)$ the jacobi matrix does not have rank 3. Is this correct?
Is there a specific reason you used a parametrisation, because you would additionally need to show that it is homeomorphic into its image (which is not hard, but still more work)?

Comment: See: [Twisted cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic) for some background on the parametrization.

Comment: At $(1,0,0,1)$, the Jacobian matrix has rank $3$, perhaps you meant $(1,0,0,0)$?

Comment: Yes I did, my mistake. Is there any way to solve this by using defining equations $f_1,f_2$? I would need to show that the manifold is also given by the roots of only to equations and then show rank 2 of its jacobi, right? Because, working with my definition of a manifold, I need exactly 2 defining equations and can't work with 3 like this.

Comment: Hint: Most points that solve $f_1$ and $f_2$ also solve $f_3$.  Which ones don't?

Comment: I found that if $x\ne 0 $ and if $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0$ then $f_3(x)=0$, is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $x\not=0$?  If $x\not=0$ means that none of the entries can be zero, but if $x\not=0$, means that some of the entries must be nonzero, then this is not enough.  Consider, for example, $x_2=0$ and $x_3=0$.  Then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are zero, but $f_3$ might not be.

Comment: I mean that $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\ne (0,0,0,0)$, so every coordinate has to be non zero.

Comment: Note that $x\not=(0,0,0,0)$ is *not* the same as every coordinate being nonzero.  It means that one coordinate is nonzero.

Comment: You are, once again, correct. Thanks!